# CakePHP Error: Plugin Migrations could not be found

Tags: windows, console, migration, cakedc, cakephp-2.5

I installed [CakeDC Migration Plugin](https://github.com/CakeDC/migrations) and trying the command `cake Migrations.migration generate`, but got the error **Error: Plugin Migrations could not be found**.

The plugin installation path is `app\Plugin\Migrations`. I have added the path to the system environment variable `D:\xampp\htdocs\myproj\app\Vendor\cakephp\cakephp\lib\Cake\Console`which is my CakePHP composer installed directory so that I could run the `cake` command globally.

```
D:\xampp\htdocs\myproj\app>cake

Welcome to CakePHP v2.5.4 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : app
Path: D:\xampp\htdocs\myproj\app\
---------------------------------------------------------------
Current Paths:

 -app: app
 -working: D:\xampp\htdocs\myproj\app
 -root: D:\xampp\htdocs\myproj
 -core: D:\xampp\htdocs\myproj\app\Vendor\cakephp\cakephp\lib

Changing Paths:

Your working path should be the same as your application path. To change your path use the '-app' param.
Example: -app relative/path/to/myapp or -app /absolute/path/to/myapp

Available Shells:
[CORE] acl, api, bake, command_list, completion, console, i18n, schema, server,test, testsuite, upgrade
[app] demo, send_mail_at_call_time, update_num_order_cache

To run an app or core command, type cake shell_name [args]
To run a plugin command, type cake Plugin.shell_name [args]
To get help on a specific command, type cake shell_name --help

D:\xampp\htdocs\myproj\app>cake Migrations.migration generate

Error: Plugin Migrations could not be found.
#0 D:\xampp\htdocs\myproj\app\Vendor\cakephp\cakephp\lib\Cake\Core\App.php(227):CakePlugin::path('Migrations')
#1 D:\xampp\htdocs\myproj\app\Vendor\cakephp\cakephp\lib\Cake\Core\App.php(549):App::path('Console/Command', 'Migrations')
#2 [internal function]: App::load('MigrationShell')
#3 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call('MigrationShell')
#4 D:\xampp\htdocs\myproj\app\Vendor\cakephp\cakephp\lib\Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher.php(249): class_exists('MigrationShell')
#5 D:\xampp\htdocs\myproj\app\Vendor\cakephp\cakephp\lib\Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher.php(200): ShellDispatcher->_getShell('Migrations.migr...')
#6 D:\xampp\htdocs\myproj\app\Vendor\cakephp\cakephp\lib\Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher.php(66): ShellDispatcher->dispatch()
#7 D:\xampp\htdocs\myproj\app\Vendor\cakephp\cakephp\lib\Cake\Console\cake.php(54): ShellDispatcher::run(Array)
#8 {main}
```

I changed the path to `app\Vendor\bin`, but still got the error:

```
D:\xampp\htdocs\myproj\app\Vendor\bin>cake Migrations.migration generate

Error: Plugin Migrations could not be found.
#0 D:\xampp\htdocs\myproj\app\Vendor\cakephp\cakephp\lib\Cake\Core\App.php(227):CakePlugin::path('Migrations')
#1 D:\xampp\htdocs\myproj\app\Vendor\cakephp\cakephp\lib\Cake\Core\App.php(549):App::path('Console/Command', 'Migrations')
#2 [internal function]: App::load('MigrationShell')
#3 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call('MigrationShell')
#4 D:\xampp\htdocs\myproj\app\Vendor\cakephp\cakephp\lib\Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher.php(249): class_exists('MigrationShell')
#5 D:\xampp\htdocs\myproj\app\Vendor\cakephp\cakephp\lib\Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher.php(200): ShellDispatcher->_getShell('Migrations.migr...')
#6 D:\xampp\htdocs\myproj\app\Vendor\cakephp\cakephp\lib\Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher.php(66): ShellDispatcher->dispatch()
#7 D:\xampp\htdocs\myproj\app\Vendor\cakephp\cakephp\lib\Cake\Console\cake.php(54): ShellDispatcher::run(Array)
#8 {main}
```

Again, I changed the path to `app\Console`, but the error is **missing file of ShellDispatcher.php**. The file exists in the `cake` global system path mentioned above, but not exist in `app\Console`.

```
D:\xampp\htdocs\myproj\app>cd Console

D:\xampp\htdocs\myproj\app\Console>cake Migrations.migration generate

Warning: include(Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher.php): failed to open stream: No su
ch file or directory in D:\xampp\htdocs\myproj\app\Console\cake.php on line 28

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher.php' for inclusion (include_path='D:\xampp\htdocs\myproj\lib;.;D:\xampp\php\PEAR') in D:\xampp\htdocs\myproj\app\Console\cake.php on line 28

Fatal error: Could not locate CakePHP core files. in D:\xampp\htdocs\myproj\app\Console\cake.php on line 29
```

### [Edit]

I have two plugins in `app\Plugin`:

```
app\
 |--Plugin\
    |-- Migrations
    |-- Qdmail
```

I have `CakePlugin::loadAll()` in `app\Config\bootstrap.php` and I tried this:

```
CakePlugin::loadAll();
var_dump(CakePlugin::loaded('Migrations'));
var_dump(CakePlugin::loaded('Qdmail'));
```

The first line returns `false` while the second line returns `true`. Probably the Migration plugin could not be loaded properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By loading the plugin using `CakePlugin::load()` in bootstrap.php solved my problem, but I don't know why `CakePlugin::loadAll()` does not load it.

```
CakePlugin::loadAll();
CakePlugin::load('Migrations');
```

Answer (score 0):

CakePlugin::loadAll() load all plugins.
So I guess that Cache is this cause.
If you remove your Cache, CakePlugin::loadAll() can load all plugins.